# Make a strong link to a category (verified by the compiler)

Tags: docusaurus

To make a link to another page I can use the file path like `presentation/thomas.mdx`, like that if the file does not exist the compiler errors.

But I also want to use categories in the `sidebars.js` (autogenerated to make a summary of items pages). I tried to specify an `id` or a `slug`... I have no way to make the compiler erroring if the link is wrong.

I know category can point to a `.mdx` file but I would like to keep the generated UI of a category, while benefiting from verified links.

For example:

```json
{
  type: 'category',
  label: 'Presentation',
  link: {
    type: 'generated-index',
    slug: 'presentation',
  },
  items: [
    'presentation/thomas',
  ],
},
```

To link to the category I have to do `[link](/docs/presentation)` and it works, but if I enter `[link](/docs/presentationaaaaa)` the compiler still accept it. (It's normal since it consider it as a relative web path... but I want to force the check over slugs or ids).

Any idea?

Thank you,